# A noise or any noise(s)?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

In Longman's *[Common Mistakes in English Grammar Practice](https://archive.org/details/CommonMistakesInEnglishGrammarPractice)*, 6th Ed. by T.J. Fitikides (2002), at #251 the author recommends using *make a noise* instead of *make noise*. The example sentences go like this:

> *Don't say:* I told them not to *make noise*.
>   *Say:* I told them not to *make a noise*.

My questions:

As it's a negative sentence, why not use *any* instead of *a*, i.e. *I told them not to make any noise(s).* Is it wrong to say to a couple of noisy students in the hallway for example, *Don't make any noise(s)*?

I've looked up the word *noise* and it's both count and non-count properties In the context that I made above which one is correct or more common:

> Don't make any noise.
>   Don't make any noises.
>   Don't make a noise.
>   Don't make noises.

Comment: Related question [The use of any with plural/singular words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116742/the-use-of-any-with-plural-singular-words).

Comment: Both ***noise*** and ***sound*** can be used as countable or uncountable nouns. When using negated forms to tell someone to be silent, the most common "uncountable" version is *[I don't want to hear] **any noise*** (i.e. - ***any*** is usually included, but idiomatically it doesn't pair well with ***noise***). For the "countable" version we usually use the singular, but note that *Don't make **a noise*** means *Don't be **loud and noisy***, but *Don't make **a sound*** means *Be **completely silent***.

Comment: @Azad My pleasure. This community has more than 67,000 questions asked over the past 6 years. Please try to search the key word(s) before asking a question. It will help you ask a more specific question about what bothers you most. Good luck.

Comment: It would be quite "normal" to tell your kids "Don't make a single noise!" when they are, say, acting up in a library.  And certainly one might tell a mechanic "I hear funny noises coming from the left rear wheel."

Comment: Using *any* is not absolutely necessary in a negative sentence. It just emphasizes the sentence meaning "no matter how much or how many". If you contrast "I don't have a choice" with "I don't have any choice", the latter emphasizes the fact (not having a choice) more.

Comment: I would not say "I told them not to make a noise". Instead I would say "I told them not to make any noise" or "I told them not to make a sound". The former means that you want people to keep the noise at reasonable level, the latter means that you want people to be completely quite.

Comment: Do not post the same question on ELU. Cross-posting is not allowed on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Rarhony: sorry for being impatient. I waited for a couple of hours but got no answers then I posted it here, too. I really needed an answer. Won't do it again ☺

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions (not necessarily in order), *noise* is generally more common than *noises*.

*Noises* connotes, to me, specific different types of noise considered together:

> I loved the night noises in St. Vincent.

Here, it includes the roosters that weren't necessarily quiet until the dawn, the distant barking dogs, the insects and other night creatures.

[*Noise*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/noise) (a sound of any kind) in general can be singular or plural in kind, and when the difference between the different kinds doesn't matter, *noise* is often used.

> The *noise* from the street was making conversation impossible.
>   Once I moved in, I found that, though I was on the ninth floor, the *noise* from the street traffic and a subway made it impossible to sleep or work.

In your example:

> I told them not to make a noise.

"Don't make *any noise*" is very common; equally valid but less common is "I told them not to make a noise." Both are a little more emphatic than *"don't make noise"*. It is similar to *"Don't make a sound"* - a very emphatic imperative. It would be much less common to say *noises* here, though clearly it wouldn't be wrong.

Idiomatically, *noise* is more common in speech than *noises*. Unless you want to call attention to the different noises (e.g. "the *noises* coming from that party were really interesting"), it will sound more natural to use *noise*.

Comment: Half of the Original Poster's question is about *any* before noise(s) and your post is not mentioning anything about it.

Comment: @Rathony - Patience is a virtue. Also, remember you can provide an answer as well.